# EF Core interceptor to influence materialization

Tags: entity-framework-core, materialized-views, interception

Is it possible to use an EF Core interceptor to influence the process of materialization when data from a database reader is converted into an object?

When not, it there another way to tell EF Core to use an instance of A1 instead of type A?

Regards,
Torsten

Comment: What is your purpose? Converting the query's result that the it A type, to A1 ? For example Convert from List<A>  to List<A1> ?

Comment: Have you check this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors

Comment: We load data as instance of A as Dbmodel with DB definition purpose (i.e. Attributes for key, maxlength etc.). But the usage purpose has other needs, like INotifiyPropertyChanged or ObservableCollection within properties. So we copy the loaded instance of A to an another type A1. In theory it should be possible to model the entity A and load the entity A1 when they are identical, or identical properties or same structure.

Comment: Automapper and ProjectTo?

Comment: Yes, Automapper is a good approach. But it is after the entity is loaded. We are looking something like DbSet<A>.LoadAs<SubtypeOfA>(...)

Answer (score 3):

EF Core's team introduced in version 7 `IMaterializationInterceptor` which is exactly what you want to use.

You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#simple-actions-on-entity-creation).
The API is quite simple.

However, the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) about interceptors does not mention (yet?) the existence of `IMaterializationInterceptor`.